# "Degree of certainty" for inductive (statistical) vs deductive (mathematical) problems

Tags: statistics, induction, axioms, philosophy

I read this when studying page 3 of statistics book "In All Likelihood" by Yudi Pawitan:

> In deductive problems the truth quality of the new theorem is the same as the quality of the 'data' (axioms, definitions and previous theorems) used in establishing it. In contrast, the degree of certainty in an inductive conclusion is typically stronger than the degree in the data constituent, and the truth quality of the conclusion improves as we use more and more data.

I don't see how this makes sense. The "truth quality", or the "degree of certainty", for deductive problems is 100%, since, beginning with some set of axioms and then proceeding with logic, we can be certain of whether some proposition true or false. On the other hand, the nature of inductive problems, such as those encountered in statistics, is such that the degree of certainty is <100% for nontrivial problems. Why is the author making this argument? Is it valid? Is my argument incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: "beginning with some set of axioms and then proceeding with logic, we can be certain of whether some proposition true or false" Only if we are certain about the premises, but the author implies that the premise data need not be 100% certain, in which case the certainty of the conclusion is not 100% either.

Comment: @lemontree Can you please give an example to illustrate?

Comment: As a mathematical example, take the [P NP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). It is known that if $P=NP$, then there are algorithms which solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time. But noone knows if $P=NP$. The majority of scientists conjecture that it's not the case, so the degree of certainty for the premise is, say, 10%. Then the conclusion "there exist polynomial algorithms for NP-complete problems" is only 10% certain as well.

Comment: @lemontree interesting. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, including the info which book/paper you got this from would possibly help potential answerers figure out what the author might have meant.

Comment: @lemontree I have edited the post.